# How do I manipulate the data within this array? javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Below I have a javascript function that reads a CSV file and interprets the data into an array within the webpage.

```
document.getElementById('file').onchange = function(){

var file = this.files[0];

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(progressEvent){
// Entire file

// By lines
var lines = this.result.split('\n');
for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
}
        $('#input').append(lines);
};
reader.readAsText(file);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    example2();

    $('#upload').bind('click', function() {
        example2();
    });
});

function example2() {
    var input = $('#input').val();
    var data = $.csv.toArrays(input);
    var html = generateTable(data);
    $('#result').empty();
    $('#result').html(html);
        console.log(data);
}
```

I now need to pull out and manipulate the data within the array but any time I try to reference the array data, it says it cannot find it.

Comment: Do you mean `console.log(data)` returns undefined in `example2`, or what?

Comment: Console.log produces the results in the array but I need to start manipulating and pulling the data from the array to use in functions, when I use something defining the variable "data" it says it cannot find it

Comment: Sounds like you're having scoping issues. Show the code *where the error happens*.

Comment: put that code in a javascript linter: the brackets don't match properly; and please do not use "bind" to attach events in jQuery, it is obsolete, the new way is "on".

Comment: I'm incredibly new to this language and do have little knowledge on how to do certain things.

The purpose is that with the code above, I can then write a function to take the array data and detail each header for the user to select which in total selects all the array data for that header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're appending lines to some element in the DOM: `$('#input')`

Why not declare a variable outside of your functions:

```
var someArray = [];
```

Then use to push to that instead or in parallel with adding to "input" element, so (you have a typo in the for loop, you append all lines instead of just current line):

```
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    $('#input').append(lines[i]);
    someArray.push(lines[i]);
};
```

After this your "someArray" is available everywhere in the page scope.

Comment: I tried to implement your way but it wasn't inputting the data into an array. Are you saying that my current defined array isn't global that way no other function can call it?

Comment: I managed to do it and now the data is in the array, all I need to do now is create a function to call and display the header data from the array into a box

Comment: sorry, i don't have time to do your homework... if you wanna be a programmer you have to try, learn, read... Hint: you need to register an event, iterate the array and add line from array into a html element.